# How to automate a command input in Colab

Tags: python, linux, google-colaboratory, speed-test

[image: As you can see in this image]
Everytime i have to agree to the speedtest terms of Ookla by typing 'Y'.
Is there any way to automate this input. (in the same cell). Such that i won't have to type 'y' personally there

I tried finding a solution on Google. But google doesn't seem to understand my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) `|` to redirect stdout to stdin.

```py
! echo YES | speedtest
```